# Prime ideals and integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Prove that if an integral domain contains exactly one prime ideal, then it's a field.

My attempt : Since the ring is an integral domain, $(0) $ is a prime ideal. So no other prime ideal exists. Now, if $I $ is a proper  ideal, then either  $I $ is maximal or we can get a proper ideal containing it. If I can somehow get a proper  maximal ideal, then it is prime. But the problem is that the ring  $R $ need not be finite. So, is my approach correct? Otherwise, how should I proceed?

Comment: Can you see what needs to be proved? Only that any non-zero element is invertible, so take $\;0\neq r\in R\;$ and look at $\;\langle r\rangle\;$ ...

Comment: Your approach is correct, I suggest that your try to find all maximal ideals of this ring, in this case there are a only maximal ideal. Because every maximal is a prime ideal, so every element different to zero is a unit then R is a field.

Comment: @DonAntonio I tried to prove  $(r) =R$ by contradiction,  but couldn't succeed. Anyway, I found out a proof saying an integral domain has a maximal ideal. So I think I can proceed as state above. Thanks.

Comment: @ThomasShelby Every proper ideal in every ring with identity is contained in a maximal ideal. It doesn't have to do with being an integral domain, really...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of least resistance is:

1. $\{0\}$ is the only prime ideal (exactly as you have reasoned)
2. All maximal ideals of $R$ are prime (easy exercise proven all over the site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68493/29335)) and hence the only possible maximal ideal is $\{0\}$.
3. Therefore $\{0\}$ is the only maximal ideal of the ring, and the only proper ideal of the ring.
4. A ring with exactly two ideals (the zero ideal and the whole ring) is a field (proven all over the site, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/101157/29335))

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ has exactly one prime ideal then its nilradical $N$ must be that ideal because it is the intersection of all the prime ideals. Then $R/N$ is a field, see here:

[Each element of a ring is either a unit or a nilpotent element iff the ring has a unique prime ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595552/each-element-of-a-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-nilpotent-element-iff-the-ring-has)

Here we have $N=0$ by assumption, see your argument, so that $R$ is a field.

Comment: The nilradical is the intersection of all prime ideals.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ a\neq 0\Rightarrow (a)=1 $ (else some max($\Rightarrow$prime) $M \supseteq  (a),$ contra $0 =$ unique prime ideal)