# Properties of Noetherian local ring (Sharp, Exercise 8.33)

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R,M)$ be a Noetherian local ring. Show that

i) If there exists a non-maximal prime ideal of $R$, then $M^{n+1} \subset M^{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

ii) If $I$ is a proper ideal of $R$ and $\sqrt{I} \neq M$ then $I +M^{n+1} \subset I +M^{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I think $M^{n+1} \subset M^{n}$ is obvious without condition about the existence of non-maximal prime ideal, doesn't it? I have no idea for this problem. Can anyone help me?

Comment: $M^{n+1} \subset RM^n=M^n$ is that right?

Comment: that seems right... isn't part (ii) then obvious as well? we are probably missing something though

Comment: I find this problem is 8.33 in the book "Steps in commutative algebra"

Comment: I think here $\subset$ is meant as " is strictly included" : some authors use this convention and add a second bar under $\subset$ to mean "is included"

Comment: @Desunkid But $M \supset M^2 \supset \cdots \supset M^n \supset M^{n+1} \supset \cdots$ is a *descending* chain.

Comment: @Desunkid For i) use Nakayama. For ii) use i) by replacing $R$ with $R/I$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\subset$ subset symbol is definitely meant to indicate strict inclusion here.

For the first part, since trivially $I^n \subseteq I^m$ for any ideal $I$ and $n \geq m$, the problem is just to prove that $M^{n+1} \not= M^{n}$ given the assumption that the ring is not $0$-dimensional.

We will show contrapositively that $M^{n+1} = M^n$ implies that the ring is $0$-dimensional.

Recall that Nakayama's lemma, in one of its incarnations, states the following:

> **Nakayama's lemma**: Let $I$ be an ideal contained in the Jacobson radical of $R$ and $M$ be a finitely generated ideal.  If $IM = M$ then $M = 0$.

In a local ring, the Jacobson radical is the unique maximal ideal, which contains our non-maximal ideal $M$.  Moreover $M$ is f.g. by the Noetherian assumption.  So if we have $MM^n = M^n$ then Nakayama says that $M^n = 0$.

If the maximal ideal is nilpotent, then every nonunit is nilpotent, and [this implies that the ring has a unique prime ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/595552/each-element-of-a-ring-is-either-a-unit-or-a-nilpotent-element-iff-the-ring-has) (good elementary exercise).

Hence the ring is $0$-dimensional.

For the second part, note that $(R/I, M/I)$ is a local Noetherian ring, too.  Again we show the contrapositive:  if $I + M^{n+1} = I + M^n$ then $\sqrt{I} = M$.  By the first part, if $I + M^{n+1} = I + M^n$ then $R/I$ is $0$-dimensional.  So $M$ is the only prime ideal of $R$ containing $I$.  But the radical of an ideal is the intersection of the primes containing it, so $\sqrt{I} = M$.

Comment: It's definitely a bad idea to solve someone homework. He had already two hints in the comments. If he needed more details could have ask.

Comment: My intuition from the abundant confusion surrounding this question and from looking at the user's asking history was that this is somebody hopping around in self-directed study rather than doing homework, and that details would be helpful.  Granted I might be very wrong about that. I tend to agree that giving out homework solutions sans dialogue doesn't help anybody.  Office hours are good.

Comment: Thank you @Badam Baplan. It's not my homework, I'd study about Nakayama's lemma and Krull intersection theorem and do some exercises about these theorems.